# Migrating from Visual Studio to Eclipse

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse

I have been a long-term .NET developer, but dabble in Java and PHP development in Eclipse from time to time.

IMHO, Visual Studio is by far the better IDE, but I love developing in other languages outside of .NET, so the transition to Eclipse is crude to say the least.

Is there any way to migrate some of my settings (especially color, hotkeys would be awesome too) without having to find the mapping myself?

For color schemes, is there something similar to http://studiostyl.es/ for Eclipse if I can't migrate?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I would love to continue using Eclipse, but it is missing the aesthetic attractiveness of VS that I could imagine others would like to see as well.

***please note***

I'm not looking for PHP.NET or the like, unless there is a free alternative.  I like many aspects of Eclipse and would like to keeping it if possible, thus the question of how to migrate TO Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For color schemes:

- http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/
- http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin

For hotkeys, this blog post may help:

- http://kristofmattei.be/2009/06/12/eclipse-ganymede-install-visual-studio-keymapping/

Comment: I can't thank you enough.  I can't believe I didn't discover this through Google throughout the years.  Thank you!!